# ndk-bundle Not Found (GameMaker: Studio 2)

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I downloaded the Android Studio and installed the ndk. GameMaker says no ndk was found. I tried to install the ndk separately but it didn't work either. What could it be?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOzJi.png)

Android Studio version 3.2.1

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to point to the specific NDK version directory such as `C:\AndroidSDK\ndk\20.0.5594570\` instead of `C:\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle`. Go to your `C:\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle` directory and see which version of NDK you installed, and then post that directory to the IDE settings instead.